# Should I reopen or create new weep holes in a brick veneer wall?

Tags: brick, weep-hole

Some portions of my house have a brick veneer wall (that is, a brick wall that is not structural; cement blocks on the other side support the structure - please correct me if I am calling it the wrong thing).

There are no weep holes as far as I can see. I strongly suspect the former owner filled them up (as he did this sort of thing everywhere, like between the basement floor and foundation walls).

If I can locate where the old weep holes were, I can just open them back up I think. But if I cannot locate them, would it be totally stupid to drill some new weep holes in the mortar?

Comment: Can you see the bottom of the bricks?

Comment: @SteveSh, yes, the brick wall ends where a paved sidewalk deal begins.

Comment: Confirm that the brick ends above the sidewalk.  Quite often a sidewalk is put in after bricks, so it is possible to be above the bottom bricks.

Comment: You don't need weep holes for any walls that surround interior spaces (those should have a perimeter drain at the foundation).  Only time you really need weep holes is for a (tall) retaining wall.

Comment: @Isherwood - Nothing in my comment, which seems to have been deleted, was speculative. I was stating a hard fact - that my brick facade has no weep holes.  There is nothing speculative about that.

Comment: @Huesmann, that's completely at odds with what I know about brick walls. Have a look at the office buildings you pass in the future. They'll often have weep holes (sometimes with string protruding).

Comment: @isherwood got a pic of such a thing?